# Return from query in swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm pretty new to Swift and I'm trying to understand how to return from the follow `execute(query)` and update the result in ContentView.

```
func latestHarteRate() {

    guard let sampleType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate) else {
        return
    }
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: Date())

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options: .strictEndDate)

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)

    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]){(sample,result,error) in guard error == nil else{
            return
        }


    let data = result![0] as! HKQuantitySample
    let unit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
    let latestHr = data.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit)
    

    print(latestHr)
    }
    
    healthStore?.execute(query)
    
}
```

}

Comment: My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68418699/getting-new-heart-rate-data-live-from-health-app/68419860#68419860) to your previous question included an `@Published` array in the model. You can just bind to that array.